# "Error response from daemon: 404 page not found" While using docker command

Tags: docker

While i'm using the docker command i'm getting below error. Anyone have solution for this? Please help me to sort out this issue.

```
akshath@akshu:~$ docker images
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
akshath@akshu:~$ docker version
Client:
Version:      1.9.1
API version:  1.21
Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a34a1d5
Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:16:54 UTC 2015
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Error response from daemon: 404 page not found
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Docker daemon answers '404 page not found' after update](https://serverfault.com/a/683467/783)", check if you have any PROXY defined (`HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`) in your current environment (`env|grep -i proxy`)

It is referenced in [issue 109](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf/issues/109#issuecomment-76449612).

Also [issue 17960](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17960) reports the same problem, and includes:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker/network/files/ /path/to/backup/docker-network-files
```

> solved the problem.
>
> (If everything goes well, /path/to/backup/docker-network-files can be deleted)

If that is not enough, chech `systemctl status docker.service` or logs, to find the real cause.

If this is still not working:

- uninstalling/ reinstalling docker can help
- make sure to move after uninstall the `/var/lib/docker/network` folder, to have a fresh start.

Exact Answer:

[issue 17083](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17083): Moving `/var/lib/docker` away solved the problem. Or: "I removed only /var/lib/docker/network and now everything works well and without containers lost."

Comment: @AkshathKumar then I need to ask if you are in the opposite situation: are you accessing (from your host which runs docker) internet through a proxy?

Comment: @VonC..I have run the app in docker container which using nginx proxy server ... the docker file looks like below....  # This image will be based on the oficial apache docker image
FROM nginx

# Maintaner name goes here
MAINTAINER akshath

EXPOSE 80 

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html/

Comment: @AkshathKumar this should not be related to an image (like nginx), but more about how docker has been installed (on your host). Are you working directly on Ubuntu? And do you need a proxy to access internet (I am not talking about docker here, just about how you access internet)

Comment: @VonC..Yes , i'm directly working from Ubuntu. I'm accessing internet through my company network gateway which requires login but there is nothing wrong with my internet connection as it was working properly till i configured the nginx proxy server using docker.

Comment: @AkshathKumar is your nginx image running right now as a container (what does a `docker ps -a` returns?) Also What is the config for this nginx?

Comment: @AkshathKumar just to be sure, can you try again after a `export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,.sock,/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @AkshathKumar OK, did you se my last edit on the answer? Did you try the `sudo mv` command?

Comment: @VonC..Thanks once again... While using above command getting below output...akshath@akshu:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/docker/network/files/ /path/to/backup/docker-network-files
mv: cannot move ‘/var/lib/docker/network/files/’ to ‘/path/to/backup/docker-network-files’: No such file or directory

Comment: @AkshathKumar Can you try and restart the docker daemon on your Ubuntu? `sudo service docker restart`

Comment: @AkshathKumar good idea. That is a good way to see if a default installation works or not.

Comment: @VonC..Yes.. Thanks a lot for your support. Let you know after installing fresh copy.

Comment: @VonC...I had tried this command 'sudo docker daemon -D -s vfs' and the outcome was... DEBU[0000] Cleaning up old shm/mqueue mounts: start.    
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: could not delete the default bridge network: network bridge has active endpoints

Comment: @AkshathKumar https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17083: Moving `/var/lib/docker` away solved the problem. Or: "I removed only `/var/lib/docker/network` and now everything works well and without containers lost."

Comment: @VonC...Thanks a lot my issue has been fixed ...:) i have used the command 'sudo mv /var/lib/docker bckup' ... Thank you very  much you saved my day :)

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem on Ubuntu 14.04. Changing the folder or removing it did nothing for me, BUT because Ubuntu never updates it's repos, my version of docker was waaaaaay out of date. I was running 1.6 when the latest is 1.11.

Follow this instructions to update Docker on Ubuntu: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/

and try again. This fixed my issue!